# Discord.js Problem: Username of new user shows up as undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Welcome to the server ${user}!`)

const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome-channel");
if(!channel) return;

channel.send(welcomeEmbed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't have `user` defined, what you need to use is [`member.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user)

```js
const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`Welcome to the server ${member.user}!`)
```

Comment: I tried that, but the only thing it shows is Welcome to the server <@a bunch of numbers>! Any help?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot that you can't have mentions or formatting in embed titles, you can use embed descriptions instead, it'd look better as well. Check my edit.

Comment: You're welcome, please accept answers that solve your questions to let others know the question has been answered and also what worked